# How to destroy an enemy when player.y greater than enemy.y

Tags: javascript, css, html, game-physics

What I want to do is make it so if the player touches the enemy from the side then the player either loses a life and or it causes the game to be over. 
But if the player jumps on top of the enemy then it causes that enemy to disappear.

when the player touches the enemy while the player is on the ground
(the players y axis is equal to the enemys y axis)...

`player.y == enemy.y`

and

when the player jumps on top of the enemy.
(the players y axis is greater then the enemys y axis)...

`player.y > enemy.y`

Here is my code so far...

```js
 Level.prototype.playerTouched = function(type, actor) {
      if (type == "enemy" && this.status == null && player.y == enemy.y) {
        this.status = "lost";
        this.finishDelay = 1;
      } else if (type == "enemy" && player.y > enemy.y) {
        this.actors = this.actors.filter(function(other) {
          return other != actor;
        });
      }
    };
```

Comment: Sort of unclear what you're asking. What is working and what is not working with this code?

Comment: So what's the problem? What are you asking?

Comment: I belive that this is the correct way of writing this in javascript

player.y <= enemy.y player y is less than or equal to enemy y

player.y > enemy.y player y is greater than enemy y. 

The problem that I am having is when I add them to my code then it dosen't work.
However the code works just fine without them. So I belive that the problem
that I am having is that I am not adding them the right way.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to deal with angular calculations in this case, then you need colliders top and bottom positions

simple logic works like that

```
if(playercollider.originY > enemycollider.originY && playercollider.originX > enemycollider.leftX && playercollider.originX < enemycollider.rightX)
{
    //Enemy gets hurt
}
else
{
    //Player gets hurt
}
```

Comment: What happens when I try to add the code is that the game freezes. So it is doing something. However I haven't gotten it to do what I want. Which is again make it so if the player touches the enemy from the side then the player either loses a life and or it causes the game to be over. But if the player jumps on top of the enemy then it causes that enemy to disappear.

Comment: thats odd, if you still wish to solve this problem, please share more code lines with us...

Comment: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mbdappbucket/platformgame2.html you can go here to see my game and just click on view source to view the code.

Comment: in the Level.prototype.playerTouched function, cannot read player's and touched actor's position values? why not...

console.log("Player Y: " + this.pos.y);
and what you get is
//Player Y: undefined